# Snapping points to polygon the point sits within in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, point-in-polygon, snapping

I am trying to snap a series of points relative to the nearest line (which i know can be achieved via "Snap geometries to layer", however, i want to restrict snapping to the polygons the points sit within.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) with this expression (replace `polygon` in line 2 with the name of your polygon layer):

```
closest_point (
    overlay_within ('polygon', boundary ($geometry))[0],
    $geometry
)
```

[image]

---

If you want to snap the points to a separate line layer, but only to those sections of the line within the polygon, use this expression:

```
closest_point (
    intersection (
        overlay_nearest ('line',$geometry)[0],
        overlay_nearest ('poly',$geometry)[0]
    ),
    $geometry
)
```

*Blue points snapped to line (red points), but not the closest point overall on the line, but only those sections that are within the polygon:*
[image]